# Gradle's Kotlin DSL script cannot start Quarkus application

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl, quarkus

I'm in my journey to (try to) migrate the Gradle script(s) –written in Groovy- that I have in a (working) Quarkus `1.1.0.Final` proof-of-concept project into Kotlin DSL, but somehow, after migrating the script(s), the application doesn't start anymore. Again, the project works fine with the Groovy Gradle script(s), so I don't know what I could be missing.

This is what I have so far in `gradle.properties`, `settings.gradle.kts`, and `build.gradle.kts`:

```
#
# Dependency Versions
kotlin.version = 1.3.61
quarkus.version = 1.1.0.Final

#
# Gradle Settings
org.gradle.configureondemand = false
org.gradle.daemon = false

#
# System Settings
systemProp.file.encoding = UTF-8
systemProp.sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
```

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    // mavenLocal() // Uncomment when needed
    gradlePluginPortal()
    mavenCentral()

    maven(url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/gradle/gradle-plugins/"))
  }

  plugins {
    id("com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro").version("0.17.0")
    id("eclipse")
    id("idea")
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt").version("1.3.0")
    id("io.quarkus").version("1.1.0.Final") // TODO: Read from gradle.properties
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm").version("1.3.61") // TODO: Read from gradle.properties
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen").version("1.3.61") // TODO: Read from gradle.properties
  }
}

rootProject.name = "kotlin-quarkus-kafka"
```

```
import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.extensions.DetektExtension
import io.quarkus.gradle.QuarkusPluginExtension
import io.quarkus.gradle.tasks.QuarkusNative
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.allopen.gradle.AllOpenExtension
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

import java.time.ZoneOffset
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

plugins {
  // id("com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro")
  id("eclipse")
  id("idea")
  id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt")
  id("io.quarkus")
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen")
}

group = "org.acme"

repositories {
  // mavenLocal() // Uncomment when needed
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  implementation(enforcedPlatform("io.quarkus:quarkus-bom:${project.property("quarkus.version")}"))

  implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
  implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.5.9")
  implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-config-yaml")
  implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin")
  implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson")
  implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-health")
  implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi")
  implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka")
  implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3")
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")

  // nativeTestImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5")
  // nativeTestImplementation("io.rest-assured:rest-assured")

  testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5")
  testImplementation("io.rest-assured:rest-assured")
  testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core")
}

//=================================================================================================
//  P L U G I N S
//=================================================================================================

configure<AllOpenExtension> {
  annotation("io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest")
  annotation("javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped")
  annotation("javax.inject.Singleton")
  annotation("javax.ws.rs.Path")
}

// configure<DefaultAvroExtension> {
//   // TODO: Specify location for schema files
//   isCreateSetters = false
//   setFieldVisibility(FieldVisibility.PRIVATE)
// }

configure<DetektExtension> {
  // ...
}

configure<QuarkusPluginExtension> {
  // ...
}

//=================================================================================================
//  T A S K S
//=================================================================================================

tasks {
  withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
      jvmTarget = "${JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8}"
    }
  }

  withType<QuarkusNative> {
    // "-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflection-config.json"
    // "-H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=resources-config.json"
    additionalBuildArgs = listOf()
  }

  withType<Test> {
    // exclude("**/Native*")
    systemProperty("java.util.logging.manager", "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
    testLogging {
      events = setOf(TestLogEvent.FAILED, TestLogEvent.SKIPPED)
      exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
      showCauses = true
      showExceptions = true
      showStackTraces = true
    }
    useJUnitPlatform()
  }
}
```

...and this is the error I'm getting:

```sh
[x80486@uplink kotlin-quarkus-kafka]$ ./gradlew clean quarkusDev
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing

> Task :clean
> Task :compileKotlin
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :quarkusDev FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':quarkusDev' (type 'QuarkusDev').
> Directory 'C:\Users\x80486\Workshop\kotlin-quarkus-kafka\build\classes\java\main;C:\Users\x80486\Workshop\kotlin-quarkus-kafka\build\classes\kotlin\main' specified for property 'workingDir' does not exist.
> Directory 'C:\Users\x80486\Workshop\kotlin-quarkus-kafka\src\main\java;C:\Users\x80486\Workshop\kotlin-quarkus-kafka\build\generated-main-avro-java;C:\Users\x80486\Workshop\kotlin-quarkus-kafka\src\main\kotlin' specified for property 'sourceDir' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 2s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a very similar issue to one of the issues fixed by George here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/6317 . Especially this commit: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/6317/commits/7b07d866e5b81b46c09d59a08556b9a796c11007 .

Not entirely sure it's the same bug though. And not totally sure, the fix will be right in your case. Especially if you have a mix of Java and Kotlin classes.

Could you create a simple reproducer and open an issue on GitHub? We will then be able to check if it's already solved or needs some more love.

Comment: All right, let me see how can I upload this proof-of-concept to GitHub since it's blocked here at work.

Comment: This is fixed as part of `1.1.1.Final` release :thumbs_up: